# Remove formatting on string literal

Tags: c#, string, formatting

Given the c# code:

```
string foo = @"
           abcde
           fghijk";
```

I am trying to remove all formatting, including whitespaces between the lines.

So far the code

```
foo = foo.Replace("\n","").Replace("\r", "");
```

works but the whitespace between lines 2 and 3 and still kept.

I assume a regular expression is the only solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried foo = foo.replace("\r\n",""); ?

Comment: That code won't compile - please use real/compilable examples.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, it's a casing issue, it's not that hard to figure out.

Comment: @msarchet: It isn't about 'figuring it out', it's about being precise. I enjoy helping, that's fun, but becoming complacent in correcting side-line issues before getting to the real problem can quickly become tedious, potentially slowing the process down - for us and the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to keep multiple lines, if not, i'd choose [CAbbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113763/cabbott)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193164/remove-formatting-on-string-literal/7193246#7193246).

```
var fooNoWhiteSpace = string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    foo.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(fooline => fooline.Trim())
);
```

1. What this does it split the string into lines ([`foo.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)),
2. trim whitespace from the start and end of each line (.Select(fooline => [`fooline.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx))),
3. then combine them back together with a new line inbetween ([`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)).

Comment: went for `foo = string.Concat(s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(f => f.Trim()));` This retains whitespace inbetween each string / per line.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
foo = Regex.Replace(foo, @"\s+", "");
```

Comment: Won't that remove the line breaks too?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Thank you @CAbbott!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
string input = @" 
           abcde 
           fghijk"; 
string output = "";
string[] parts = input.Split('\n');

foreach (var part in parts)
{
    // If you want everything on one line... else just + "\n" to it
    output += part.Trim();
}
```

This should remove everthing.

Answer (score 0):

If the whitespace is all spaces, you could use

```
foo.Replace(" ", "");
```

For any other whitespace that may be in there, do the same. Example:

```
foo.Replace("\t", "");
```

Comment: What about the difference between ASCII characters `0032` and `0160`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Replace(" ", "")` your dealing with a string literal which mean all the white space is part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string test = @"
            abcde
            fghijk";
```

**EDIT**: Addded code to only filter out white spaces.

```
string newString = new string(test.Where(c => Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) == false).ToArray());
```

Produces the following: abcdefghijk

Comment: This will remove all numbers and non-letter characters, in addition to whitespace/formatting.

Comment: @Jim: Edited answer to only remove white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I've written something similar to George Duckett but put my logic into a string  extension method so it easier for other to read/consume:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string RemoveTabbing(this string fmt)
    {
        return string.Join(
            System.Environment.NewLine,
            fmt.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(fooline => fooline.Trim()));
    }
}
```

you can the call it like this:

```
string foo = @"
       abcde
       fghijk".RemoveTabbing();
```

I hope that helps someone